# Относительная ссылка в условном форматировании Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

На googel Sheets в условном форматировании прописал формулу =REGEXMATCH(C1;ДВССЫЛ("P1"))=ИСТИНА - Работает но проверяет только по маске расположенной в ячейке P1.
Пытаюсь сделать, что бы сверяла с маской расположенной на каждой строке со сверяемым значением например: =REGEXMATCH(C101;ДВССЫЛ("P101"))=ИСТИНА так тоже работает но для конкретной строки.
Хочу что бы проверка была по всему столбцу С
Пытался сделать так: =REGEXMATCH(C1, ДВССЫЛ(P1)) не работает
=REGEXMATCH(C1, ДВССЫЛ("""" & P1 & """")) не работает
Подскажите что не так делаю?

Comment: ДВССЫЛ(P1) - не то? Непонятно, опишите точнее задачу

Comment: Нет, так тоже не работает.

Comment: Прочитайте еще второе предложение в предыдущем сообщении...

Comment: Так я описал подробнее задачу.

Comment: Извините, но без примера непонятно. Возможно, ИНДЕКС поможет. Но надо увидеть и пощупать

Comment: вот сделал тестовую табличку: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ot_VOQu1YHA1BYevG_5ztqEocSvZriEH8L4sxVnRTH0/edit?usp=sharing Надо, что бы нижние ячейки тоже светились.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Диапазон условного форматирования - столбец:

```
=IF(A1<>"";REGEXMATCH(A1;INDEX(B:B;Row())))
```

Comment: Супер, Спасибо огромное - работает как надо!

Comment: Теперь понимаете, что пример - это 70-80% решения? :)

Comment: Да, Спасибо. В следующие разы буду прикладывать примеры.